# When colors with the prefix 'on' are used in Vuetify 3

Tags: css, colors, vuetify.js

I have studied the documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#theme) and [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/), and took as a basis the original styles that I found in the styles block on the site page. I have a question regarding some colors with the prefix `on-`. Where and in what cases can I see the use of the following colors, and is it worth redefining them?

Do I understand correctly that these are the colors that will be used on top of others? For example, `background: #000` and `on-background: #FFF` will give **white text** on a **black background**?

There were no issues with other colors and their redefinition.

```
'on-background': '#FFFFFF',
'on-surface': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning': '#FFFFFF',
'on-accent': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-lighten-5': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-lighten-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-lighten-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-lighten-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-lighten-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-darken-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-darken-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-darken-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-primary-darken-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-lighten-5': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-lighten-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-lighten-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-lighten-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-lighten-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-darken-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-darken-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-darken-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-secondary-darken-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error-lighten-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error-lighten-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error-lighten-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error-lighten-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error-darken-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error-darken-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error-darken-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-error-darken-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning-lighten-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning-lighten-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning-lighten-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning-lighten-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning-darken-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning-darken-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning-darken-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-warning-darken-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info-lighten-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info-lighten-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info-lighten-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info-lighten-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info-darken-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info-darken-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info-darken-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-info-darken-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success-lighten-4': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success-lighten-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success-lighten-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success-lighten-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success-darken-1': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success-darken-2': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success-darken-3': '#FFFFFF',
'on-success-darken-4': '#FFFFFF',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'theme-color' is the background-color of an element, 'on-theme-color' is the color meant for text that appears against that background

[Vuetify Playground demonstration](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)